# Date.TryParse for decimal converting date

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have string that contains "1.3" and I am checking with Date.TryParse method. It automatically converting into "1/3/2010". How to handle this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I want, If the string is in date format then it should come into condition otherwise it should skip condition. Why "1.3" is true to date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why `1.3f` returns true on `TryParse`? Because the `TryParse` method take that as valid input. Probably, some of supported date formats separates token by dot. You may want to try method:

`DateTime.TryParse(String, IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles, DateTime%)` and as IFormatProvider supply `CultureInfo.createSpecificCulture("en-US or whatever you want")`.

or

`DateTime.TryParseExact`, which allows you to supply specific format to parse the string into a DateTime object.